# Send non english-text using adb (input keyevent) or using monkeyrunner

Tags: android, shell, adb, monkeyrunner

I would like to send some non-english text to an Android device.
I have been trying both the monkeyrunner type command and adb shell command (input keyevent ...), with no success.
Please help.

Comment: have u got solution of this problem?if yes please share.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [ADBKeyBoard](https://github.com/senzhk/ADBKeyBoard) created by [Eric Tang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2764618/eric-tang)

Check [adb shell input unicode character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224549/adb-shell-input-unicode-character) or 
[github](https://github.com/senzhk/ADBKeyBoard) to find more details.

Answer (score 0):

I am using monkeyrunner to send non-english characters in SMS.

I just put

```
# coding=utf8
```

in the beggining of my python file, it worked perfectly for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: How does it work? It has to use adb behind the scenes, no?