# adb shell input unicode character

Tags: android, text, unicode, adb

Knowing the basic key mappings described in [ADB Shell Input Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7789826/adb-shell-input-events) I get the emulation of text input and special keys working quite well. But what about Unicode characters? For instance I want to use umlauts from the German QWERTZ keyboard layout.

This gets me:

```
$ adb shell input text ö
Killed
```

So it seems to crash and

```
adb shell input text \xFC
```

prints xFC on the input. I have tried to the the events with `getevent` but I haven't found a direct mapping, I've also looked into the keymapping file `/system/usr/keylayout/Qwerty.kl`

I believe the only possibility is via the clipboard, but as pointed out in the question [Pasting text into Android emulator clipboard using adb shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283446/pasting-text-into-android-emulator-clipboard-using-adb-shell)  it seems to be unknown how to use it for Android Ice Cream Sandwich or later..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input` won't work because it can only send single key event through the virtual keyboard (check the source code if you don't know what I mean).

I think the only way left is using **Instrumentation**. I guess you can create a test for your **Activity** and then do something like this:

```
                final Instrumentation instrumentation = getInstrumentation();
                final long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                final long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                
                final KeyEvent altDown = new KeyEvent(downTime, eventTime, KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_GRAVE, 1, KeyEvent.META_ALT_LEFT_ON);
                final KeyEvent altUp = new KeyEvent(downTime, eventTime, KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
                        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_GRAVE, 1, KeyEvent.META_ALT_LEFT_ON);
                
                instrumentation.sendKeySync(altDown);
                instrumentation.sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A);
                instrumentation.sendKeySync(altUp);
                instrumentation.sendKeySync(altDown);
                instrumentation.sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_E);
                instrumentation.sendKeySync(altUp);
                instrumentation.sendKeySync(altDown);
                instrumentation.sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_I);
                instrumentation.sendKeySync(altUp);
                instrumentation.sendKeySync(altDown);
                instrumentation.sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_O);
                instrumentation.sendKeySync(altUp);
                instrumentation.sendKeySync(altDown);
                instrumentation.sendCharacterSync(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_U);
                instrumentation.sendKeySync(altUp);
```

This will send the modified keys: **àèìòù**

#### update 2022

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71367206/236465 shows another solution using [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) and [CulebraTester2-public](https://github.com/dtmilano/CulebraTester2-public) backend.

Comment: While this seems to work for the accented letters you list, I don't think it works for German umlauts such as äöü. Do you know what key combinations to use to produce these?

Comment: @FD_ Hi, Finally I found the answer.
Firstly, on this page, [Key Map](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-character-map-files)  you can know the unicodes of combining diacritical dead key characters.   

'\u0300': Grave accent. à  

'\u0301': Acute accent.  á  

'\u0302': Circumflex accent.   â  

'\u0303': Tilde accent.  ã  

'\u0308': Umlaut accent. ä    

and  on this page [Virtual.kcm](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/data/keyboards/Virtual.kcm)  you can know how the unicode can be constructed.

Answer (score 26):

I wrote a virtual keyboard that accept broadcast intent, so you can send unicode characters to the editText view via adb.

for e.g.
adb shell am broadcast -a ADB_INPUT_TEXT --es msg "你好嗎! Hello!"

Here is the github project:
https://github.com/senzhk/ADBKeyBoard

Hope this little project would help.

Comment: thank you very much for patching a lack in android. you're the real mvp !

Answer (score 10):

Actually ADBKeyBoard is very good! Thanks for Eric Tang !

Some useful extensions for comfortable usage:

Switch to ADBKeyBoard from adb:

```
   adb shell ime set com.android.adbkeyboard/.AdbIME
```

Check your available le virtual keyboards:

```
ime list -a
```

Use **simple quote** characters -not double as in example above- if your shell not accepts "!" (explanation sign)

```
adb shell am broadcast -a ADB_INPUT_TEXT --es msg 'Accented characters here'
```

Switch back to original virtual keyboard: (swype in my case...)

```
adb shell ime set com.nuance.swype.dtc/com.nuance.swype.input.IME
```

Use adb over wifi to simplify your life... :)

Comment: This requires the app to be installed on the device. Isn't there any way to achieve it using "adb" itself?

Comment: Thanks, I don't know adb can connect with WIFI before now, it help me a lot.